# - Large # of MySQL lost connections and failures to connect

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have been seeing a LOT of errors like this in the log files for one of our sites:

- Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet'
- Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'
- Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
- User already has more than 'max_user_connections' active

In fact, the log files are filling up with these errors. The site in question gets only 500 visitors per day, although it does process 100,000+ queries in a given day when certain background PHP scripts are run.

Connections are always closed explicitly after a script finishes. There are no persistent connections.

This happens with just about every script that is run from time to time and the MySQL server crashes a couple of times a day.

Could this be some sort of configuration issue?

- MySQL 5.1.69-cll
- PHP 5.2.17
- Apache 2.2.24

Comment: Add more specific data.

Comment: Do you have long running queries that are causing connections to stack up (thus hitting max connections limit)?  Unfortunately, this may a be a problem that is impossible to troubleshoot via SO.  My suggestions would be to look at MySQL slow query log (if you have it enabled - if you don't have it enabled, enable it) to see what sort of queries you might have showing up in there.  Also you might want to monitor the DB status using `show processlist` to see if you have times when long-running queries are causing other queries to have to wait for table locks.

Comment: @MikeBrant There are a few that are long running, but they only run 2-3 times per day at most and usually last 30 seconds max. Max user connections is set to 250 and I've never seen more than 25 connections to the server at once.

Comment: Uninformed guess: The scripts in question are for some reason creating a new connection to MySQL for every query they make (or some similar highly iterative case). The previous connections aren't closed, but instead remain idling until the script finishes, at which point all connections are shut down by the exit routines of PHP.

Comment: Quite possible, but no idea how that would happen. I only know of 1 mysql_connect() instance per script.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this behavior once before in a stateless three tier architecture with load balancing at each tier. In this instance one of the app tier servers had an old password for the database credentials but all of the other app tier servers had the new correct password. Probably not your issue but your description is pretty identical.